# How to detect invalid combination of Spring 3 with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In this answered question from 2014 [Context initialization failed Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884985/context-initialization-failed-spring), Dave Morrissey resolved it by explaining that the OP was using Spring 3 with Java 8.
I had the same problem while running an old training course and I've upvoted Dave's answer (but my reputation is not high enough so the publicly displayed vote hasn't changed).

Even knowing the resolution and understanding the underlying causes, I can't see how to detect this problem in my own project or the posted one.  The only clue appears to be the illegal argument exception which is thrown during context initialisation.

So, how can one detect this conflict - because sooner or later it will happen again (although hopefully in my own work I would remember)?  Is it just one of those "This is what happens, and that's usually the reason" or is there something you can latch onto which definitively shows the cause?

Thanks,
Jonathan