# Encountering error during context initialization in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Getting an error when starting sprint boot application with PostgreSQL database, I've tried to find a solution, but haven't found one thus far.

**Here's the error:**

> 2018-03-29 17:48:17.945  WARN 13508 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>   2018-03-29 17:48:17.950  INFO 13508 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2018-03-29 17:48:17.975  INFO 13508 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-03-29
>   17:48:17.988 ERROR 13508 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]   at
>   com.lowes.promo.PromoApplication.main(PromoApplication.java:14)
>   [bin/:na] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException  at
>   org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.(MetadataSources.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:179)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]     ... 16 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 27 common frames omitted

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884985/context-initialization-failed-spring

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if you have right dependency added to your build tool config file.
If you are using maven,check your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException*

suggests you are missing the dependency for jaxb-api

Comment: glad it worked.May be you can accept the answer,it will help others as well.Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me too. Was building a 2 year-old spring todo example app (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mysql-spring-boot-todo) with Java 11 and I needed to do this (among other things) to get the app running. I upvoted, thanks for the solution.